# Calling a function that a PDO query error

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I'm new to PDO so apologies if this maybe rather simple, however I've spent hours trying to find an answer and couldnt therefore had to post.

I have a function stored in my functions file:

```
   function insertlogs($user)
      {
    $page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $ip = GetIP();
    $ub = getBrowser();
    $regdate = date("Y-m-d");
    $regtime = date("H:i:s");


              try{
                  $sql =  "INSERT INTO admin_logs (id, 
                   page, 
                   ip, 
                   browser, 
                   loggedinuser, 
                   date, 
                   time) VALUES (
                   :gid, 
                   :page, 
                   :ip, 
                   :ub, 
                   :user, 
                   :regdate, 
                   :regtime )";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);         


$stmt->bindParam(':gid', $gid );       
$stmt->bindParam(':page', $page); 
$stmt->bindParam(':ip', $ip);
$stmt->bindParam(':ub', $ub); 
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);   
$stmt->bindParam(':regdate', $regdate); 
$stmt->bindParam(':regtime', $regtime);


$stmt->execute(); 



}

catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
 }}
```

When I run this independently it works fine.  However when I call this function insertlogs($user);  Its gives me the Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in....  error.

I've checked connection and that seems fine, I just cant figure it out?  Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `$db` is a `PDO` object?

Comment: You haven't defined `$db` anywhere.

Comment: Does the function has access to `$db`?

Comment: Yes sorry it has been defined in my config file - $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' .  $config['db']['dbname'] , $config['db']['username'] , $config['db']['password']);  It works for all other PDO statements, and when i take it out of the functions file and add the code into the main file which I am using it works.  For some reason as is been called from another file it doesnt work

Comment: @skippy That is not how PHP works. Read up on variable scope in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @peehaa I have defined it in my config file.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes it does, I'm at a lost :(

Comment: @skippy yes you already said that. Please read the link I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run this independently it works fine. However when I call this
>   function insertlogs($user); Its gives me the Fatal error: Call to a
>   member function prepare() on a non-object in.... error.

I suppose by "I run this independently" - you mean you run the code out of the scope of the function. When you are calling it as a function, and $db is a global variable, php doesn't know about it. And thinks, it is local, look at the 2-nd example here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

So, either pass it as a second variable (preferable):

```
function insertlogs($user, &$db)
```

Or use global:

```
function insertlogs($user)
{
    global $db;
```

Comment: Thanks @user4035.  I should of known better :)